# magento how to get Json Config by product id

Tags: magento

I am in need to get the Json Config by product id or sku in the product listing page for a particular category.

I can see that `getJsonConfig` is decalred in Product options block where only one particular product is showing thats why it can show Json Config without saying the product id. But I am in product list page.

Is there any way to get it like below?

```
$this->getJsonConfig($productId);
```

Comment: whats the product type ?

Comment: Its needed for simple and bundled

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$this->getJsonConfig()
```

The method is part of

```
class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
```

and it calls

```
 /* @var $product Mage_Catalog_Model_Product */
 $product = $this->getProduct();

public function getProduct()
{
    if (!Mage::registry('product') && $this->getProductId()) {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($this->getProductId());
        Mage::register('product', $product);
    }
    return Mage::registry('product');
}
```

So to use it ( in any other page ) you have to set product in the block instance as below :

```
Mage::register('product', $_product); // add the product object in the registry
$block = Mage::getBlockSingleton('Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View'); // Instantiate the product view block
echo $block->getJsonConfig();
```

Comment: It gives error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function getMetaTitle() on a non-object in /......./app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php on line 56

Comment: Sorry, i haven't looked at it, I have edited the solution, it should work now

Comment: in what phtml file you trying to add this ? paste your code in http://pastebin.com/

Comment: I am working in the /app/design/frontend/default/my_theme/template/catalog/product/list.phtml with code http://pastebin.com/CAtaZsdf

Comment: Can you look at the code above i have modified it !there is no more setProductId() you have to put the product in the registry. I have edited it, take a look !

Comment: Thank you so much. Now its working. My product object variable was $product. I misunderstood that. Now its working by replacing the $_product with $product.

Answer (score 4):

I found a simple solution for configurable product view page.

Hope that will help.

```
    if ($_product->isConfigurable())
      {  $block1 = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view');
         $block1->setProduct($_product);
         $configPrice = $block1->getJsonConfig();   //var_dump( $config = $block->getJsonConfig`enter code here`()  );

         $block2 = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_type_configurable');
         $block2->setProduct($_product);
         $config = $block2->getJsonConfig();  
      }

<?php if ($_product->isConfigurable()): ?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
       var optionsPrice = new Product.OptionsPrice(<?php echo $configPrice ?>);
   </script>

<script type="text/javascript">
               var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $config ?>);
            </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```